# Minimizing and maximizing matrix product norm

Tags: matrices, optimization, normed-spaces

Given two complex matrixes $M$ and $P$, is there an analytical method to find $R$, a complex matrix of norm $1$ (I'm open about the choice of the norm) such that

> $$\parallel\text{Re}(MRP))\parallel$$
>
> (where Re is the real part) is minimized or maximized?

Comment: R complex matrix of norm 1

Comment: And I was for getting, MR and RP shall have maximum rank (otherwise for minimization null space is enough)